# Find height of table after creating & populating it in python-pptx

Tags: xml, python-pptx

I am working with a table and would like to query its final height after it has been populated with values. This way I will be able to adjust its position on the slide (graphicframe.top) according to how large it is. I add the table with these lines:

`graphicframe = shapes.add_table(rows = 41, cols = 5, left = Inches(0), top = Inches(2), width = Inches(5.7), height = Inches(4))
table = graphicframe.table`

And then loop through its cells to populate them individually. The table height changes to accommodate the input (for example: text may wrap on to 2 lines, increasing the height, a large number of rows may push the table to be taller than the height I originally specified, etc).

graphicframe.height returns the original height which I inputted to add_table, and not the final height after data population. table.rows[i].height does the same.

I found what looks to be the height of each row in the XML file, and those also correspond to the original height from add_table, not the empirical final height of the table after data population. From the XML file, there are 41 lines that specify height h, corresponding to the 41 rows in my table. They look like this: < a:tr h="89209" > ...< /a:tr >

Do you know if the empirical height of my table (after it is populated) is recorded anywhere?? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you cannot determine the rendered height of a table you have just created with `python-pptx`. This is because any height adjustments for "fit" are made by the PowerPoint rendering engine, which is not available until you open the file with PowerPoint.

You may be able to use the approach you mention (adding up row heights), but it would only be accurate *after* opening the presentation with PowerPoint and possibly visiting that slide and perhaps making a small adjustment to the table. You'll have to experiment to see what, if anything, causes PowerPoint to rewrite the table row heights to their rendered values. Note that this behavior may be different between PowerPoint and LibreOffice.